# SparkSQL second explode after the first explode

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following commands to do a second explode after the first explode:

```
myExplode = sqlContext.sql("select explode(names) as name_x from myTable")
myExplode = sqlContext.sql("select explode(name_x) as name1 from myTable")
myExplode.show(6,False)
```

Then I got errors:
 `u"cannot resolve 'name_x' given input columns: [names, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC]; line 1 pos 15"`

However, the first explode works just fine. Is there anything I did wrong in my second explode?

---

Here is an example:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|names                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[Max,White,WrappedArray(SanDiego)],3], [[Spot,Black,WrappedArray(SanDiego)],2]]|
|[[[Michael,Black,WrappedArray(SanJose)],1]]                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After the first explode, I got :

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|name_x                                   |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[[Max,Black],3]                          |
|[[Spot,White],2]                         |
|[[Michael,Yellow],1]                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I now want to make a second explode on name_x, so I can get [Max,Black], [Spot, White], and [Michael, Yellow]. After this, I even want to do a third explode so I can get only Max, Spot and Michael and put them in a new column. Is this something possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You are perform the second explode on the same with a field that doesn't exist. What did you expect it to do ?

Comment: because the [names] column is an array of array. So after the first explode open up the outer array, I want to open up the second (inner) array. Thanks!

Comment: Posting a sample data set always helps others trying to resolve your issue.

Comment: Please find the example added in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `explodes` after the first one. You are just selecting part of the data. Explode takes a single row and creates more rows based on that row. That's exactly what your first explode does, and that's correct. For the second and subsequent transformations, you are not creating new rows -- you are creating new columns. You can create a new column with `withColumn` or by using `select`.

In your case, you are trying to get to nested data within a `StructType`. To get to individual fields in a `StructType`, you use `getField`. Something like:

```
`df.withColumn("newColumn", $"name_x".getField("fieldName"))
```

You will have to figure out what `fieldName` to use -- if you are not sure, just use `printSchema` on your `DataFrame` and take a peak.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is actually the element don't have a field name. [[Max,Black],3]   is just a tuple. I tried to do df.withColumn("newColumn", df.name_x.getField(_1)) , but it doesn't work. How do I get information when  the fieldName is not available? Thanks!